# How can I check with Javascript if the Lync Addon is installed in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, add-on, lync

Is there a solution to detect if the Lync-Addon is installed and active in my Internet Explorer using Javascript?

I know how to detect an Addon like Adobe Reader:

```
try {
    new ActiveXObject("AcroPDF.PDF");
    alert("Adobe Reader is installed");
} catch (err) {
    alert("Adobe Reader is not installed - " + err);
}
```

But i dont know how i can detect the Lync-Addon.
Is there an ActiveX-Object like the Adobe Reader one?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english im not a native speaker.

Comment: We don't even know what the Lync add on is. Can you provide a link and more information about what it does, how it installs itself into the browser, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The Lync plugin (Lync 2013) registers in Internet Explorer as follows:

```
Name:                   Lync Browser Helper
Publisher:              Microsoft Corporation
Type:                   Browser Helper Object
Architecture:           32-bit and 64-bit
Version:                15.0.4420.0
File date:              ‎01 ‎October ‎2012, ‏‎21:47
Date last accessed:     ‎12 ‎February ‎2013, ‏‎08:11
Class ID:               {31D09BA0-12F5-4CCE-BE8A-2923E76605DA}
Use count:              47
Block count:            0
File:                   OCHelper.dll
Folder:                 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15
```

One of the objects exposed is the `NameCtrl`:

```
new ActiveXObject('Name.NameCtrl');
```

This should not error if the Lync client is installed.

As @Webritos mentions, the real ActiveX object seems to be new `"OCHelper.BrowserHelper.1"`. However, when you try to instantiate that, you get the following error (at least in IE11 with Lync2013):

```
new ActiveXObject("OCHelper.BrowserHelper.1");
"Automation server can't create object"
```

Comment: So, is there a way to check if that registry is enabled using Javascript?

Comment: Added the ActiveX constructor for the `NameCtrl` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
new ActiveXObject("OCHelper.BrowserHelper.1");
```

Where 'OCHelper.BrowserHelper.1' is the ProgID of the Lync Browser Helper.

You can use this program to obtain information about ActiveX components installed on your computer http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/axhelper.html

About'Name.NameCtrl', I believe is not related to Lync (but it can be used for things like showing online user in a website) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms455335%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: I listed my ActiveX components as well, and found that "OCHelper.BrowserHelper.1" too. However, it cannot be created and thus is useless. For the `NameCtrl` bit, it definitely needs Lync, but I don't know for sure if it installs with the Lync client or not.

Comment: It can be created, change your security settings (google the error). Lyncs is for companies, so in a intranet, those settings can be defined as default. NameCtrl is installed with office, but Lync can be installed without office, so is not a good way.